# Question on matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

Suppose I have a vector field $F(x)=Ax$ where $A$ is a matrix. How can I express $Sx$ without $A$ (use $F$ instead)? Here $S=\dfrac{A+A^T}2$ is symmetric part of $A$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could express $A$ in terms of $F$ by noting that
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}F(e_1)& \cdots & F(e_n)\end{bmatrix}
$$
Where $e_1,\dots,e_n$ is the standard basis.  From there, you can apply the formula for $S$.